# "Fix Your Time Step" Variable or Fixed Physics "timeStep" parameter for Step in Box2D?

Tags: c++, box2d

I have seen multiple contradictory articles on this topic. Have been trying to implement the Should the function call

```
b2World->Step(timeStep, velocityIterations, positionIterations);
```

have timeStep as a constant value? Or should the timeStep vary based on a frame time accumulator, like in "https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/"?

My question comes from gameplay that seems 'too fast', whereas before I 'fixed' my timestep sometimes the physics would would run at a smooth rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get the most consistent physics behaviour if you use a fixed timestep (constant value).

The "Fix Your Timestep" article you linked does *not* recommend using a varied timestep for physics. It says exactly the opposite. The variable time component is used only for interpolation and display, not simulation.

Comment: The variable time component for interpolation being 'alpha', in reference to the "Fix Your Time Step" article?

Comment: That is part of the variable time component of the game loop, yes.